# Using PhoneGap Build for different platforms

Tags: cordova, build, multiplatform

As I understand we give PhoneGap Build the 'www' folder with our Html, Css and JS (**especially cordova.js**) and it returns us packages for necessary platforms.

But as far as I know there are different cordova.js files for different platforms. So how PhoneGap Build prepares these packages? Does it replace cordova.js for every platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Build process injects the correct *.js. In fact, you are warned not to include any phonegap.js files for this reason.